# Using Ember Data with non standard REST API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to hook up Ember Data to work with an existing REST API. The problem that I am running into is that the REST implementation does not conform to how Ember Data expects things to be done. I have scoured the web for documentation that would suggest how to make things work, but short of writing my own DS.Adapter implementation I am at a loss.

Here is what my request looks like:

```
/api/user/12345
```

which provides the following response:

```
{
    data: {
        ID: '12345',
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone',
        emailAddr: 'fred.flintstone@example.com'
    }
}
```

Ember expects "data" to be "user". Unfortunately I cannot easily change the API. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of you could achieve this, would be by creating your own serializer and override the [`extract`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L270) function:

```
App.RESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extract: function(loader, json, type, record) {
    var root = 'data';

    if (json[root]) {
      if (record) { loader.updateId(record, json[root]); }
      this.extractRecordRepresentation(loader, type, json[root]);
    }
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    serializer: App.RESTSerializer.create()
  })
});
```

> Please note that this modification assumes that the content of your request will always be under the `data` key of your JSON.

Also worth mentioning is that the original [`extract`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L270) method has two lines which are not included in the example:

```
 this.sideload(loader, type, json, root);
 this.extractMeta(loader, type, json);
```

this makes you loose `side loading` functionality and `metadata` extraction. I hope loosing this functionality is not a *show stopper* for your use case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @mzabriskie, glad I could help, plase don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, so future folks stumbling upon this will know it worked for you, thanks :)